# Can Alexa read Kindle books in the United Kingdom?

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo, united-kingdom

Is there any way to make Alexa read Kindle books in the UK? I couldn't find any options to do that.

Comment: If it works just in the US, then this may be related: http://iot.stackexchange.com/a/282/78

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about media consumption **not the Internet of Things**.

Comment: Alexa is part of IoT and we've over 50 questions related to it, so it is about Internet of Things. So I don't know what do you mean by media consumption.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Amazon.com help section you can use the following commands to make Alexa read your ebooks:

> **Listen to a Kindle book:** "Read my Kindle book." / "Read my book, '[title].'" / “Play the Kindle book, '[title].'” / “Read '[title].'”
>
> **Pause the Kindle book:** "Pause." / "Stop."
>
> **Continue listening to your Kindle book:** "Play." / "Resume."
>
> **Go to the next or previous paragraph:** "Skip back." / "Skip ahead." / "Go back." / "Go forward." / "Next." / "Previous."

What doesn't work so far are comics and graphic novels.

Here is the corresponding [section](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201975870) from Amazon.com help.

Comment: Do you know if this works in the UK specifically? I've heard [reports](https://www.amazon.co.uk/forum/-/Tx19P5HL5MX1COZ/ref=ask_ql_ql_al_hza?asin=B01DFKBL68) that it doesn't, but I haven't tested it myself.

Answer (score 6):

I've just tried it with mine but she says I don't have any books in my Audible account. I do have books in my kindle account so I guess it is not rolled out in the UK yet.

I wasn't trying to use Audible as I don't have an Audible account. I've now tried the keyword "Listen to a Kindle book" with a book name I have in my Kindle account. Alexa says she can't find the book. I've been into the Amazon UK website and tried to "deliver" the book to my Echo or Echo Dot but those options are currently greyed out unlike my Kindle reader devices

Reading a [blog post](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/how-to-find-kindle-ebooks-alexa-can-read-to-you/) today it seems that you need to have books that Alexa can read aloud