# How do I train my Amazon Echo to understand my voice more accurately?

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo, voice-recognition

The problem I have with these voice activated devices is that it doesn't always understand my voice correctly. I'm mostly focused on the Amazon Echo; in this post I am asking:

How can I train my Amazon Echo to help it understand my voice more accurately so I don't have to shout at the device?

Answer (score 8):

In the US, you can use the [Voice Training feature](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201601940) in the Alexa app. The option can be found by going to the Alexa app, selecting *Settings*, then *Voice Training*, then *Start Session*.

You will then be instructed to speak several phrases to help train your device to recognise your voice. Amazon provide the following instructions:

> During a Voice Training session, say each of the 25 different phrases in the app to your Alexa device. Your device processes every phrase you say, even if you don't finish a session. For best results:
>
> - Speak normally to your Alexa device.
> - Sit or stand where you normally speak to your Alexa device.
> - If you have a voice remote, do not use it during Voice Training.

The option seems to be unavailable in the UK, however (and presumably Germany also), according to [this reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/amazonecho/comments/5aoug0/voice_training_uk/). In that case, you'll just have to speak as clearly as possible, and hope for the best. You *might* have some luck [switching to the US language skills](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/281/how-to-use-english-alexa-skills-on-my-german-echo-dot) - if anyone wishes to test this, it would be helpful.

Also, be aware this this doesn't apply for devices using the Alexa Voice Service - only the Echo, Echo Dot and Tap are supported according to the documentation.

Comment: Yep, that's not available in Germany yet

Answer (score 0):

For me, all of a sudden, one day it asked me to say some phrases so that it could accurately identify me.

However you can do it in the Alexa App.

- More
- Settings
- Your Profile and Family
- Voice Id
- Delete Voice Id

And then you can set it up again.