# How can I make Alexa read my United Kingdom Audible books from an Echo device in India?

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

I have many audio books purchased in United Kingdoms Audible account. I can still hear them on my smartphone. I have recently moved to India and purchased amazon echo device. I do not have any books in my Audible India account. Alexa always says no books in my account hence I wanted to listen the books from my UK audible account through Alexa as I have purchased them?

How can I do that?

Note : I know I can play it via Bluetooth but is there any other easier way?

Comment: This might be related and help: https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/282/78

Answer (score 1):

I found out a workaround as of now using my Xiomi Redmi Note phone.

MIUI has a feature of duel app. Hence I just created a dual app for audible and logged in as india account. Now I have 2 icons for audible one of UK and one for India and both can download books independently.

How to enable dual app on MIUI phones.
Go to setting--> Apps --> Dual Apps --> Enable audible app

once enabled you can login in your second app with other country.

Alas only 2 apps can be created and only available in Xiaomi devices in MIUI OS as far as I know.

But still solves the issue.